# Dynamically Insert Variables into DB Table using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, prepared-statement, setter

I was working with `PreparedStatement` today and noticed that it used `setString()`, `setTimestamp()` etc. to insert variables into the DB.

I basically have 20 tables each with at least 15 columns and it would not be feasible for me to manually write down all the setters. Considering that I have an `ArrayList Vals` which contains all the variables to be inputted in String format (obtained by `getString()` using `PreparedStatement` itself), is there any way I can do an insert without using expressly using the setters? That would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Object/Relational Mapping (ORM) then you will not have to deal with all of that....try Hibernate. [Here is an example to get you started](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)